# Reading values from Json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

https://plnkr.co/edit/zvYbaoutennKArgifmky?p=preview

I have added the working fiddle.I want to read the size values from `flare.json`

file,saved in the fiddle and find the maximum and minimum size values. I have tried using `JSON.parse` method in `index.html` but its not working.I am just a beginner to visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fork of your plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Pxpeur2CGYZXvWswX9ef

I initialized some variables like this:

```
var minSize=Infinity, maxSize=-Infinity;
```

And then added these conditionals to your `recurse` function:

```
if(node.size<minSize)
    minSize=node.size;
if(node.size>maxSize)
    maxSize=node.size;
```

I expect there is a better way to do this, and hope you'll share once you find it.

Comment: Thank you soo much Sir... This is the output I  needed...Sir...for max and min values...:-)

Comment: Sir...Now I want to perform normalization on this data... I want to select a normalized value of any range.. Suppose the ranges are set as a=264 and b=743.The normalized value of any value x in the dataset is calculated:

a + (x-A)(b-a) / (B-A), Where A and B are max and min values.

Comment: Already we found max and min values.... Im getting confused on how to initialize the normalized range values again and find the normalized value? I am just a beginner Sir.. Need your guidance...